# how to get flash video stream URL from website without browser (telediario, rtve)

Tags: flash, video-streaming, bash-scripting

I want to access the video stream URL of telediario from spanish television (RTVE) which you can find here in a flash player: http://www.rtve.es/alacarta/videos/telediario/

I want to do this with linux scripting, **without** a webbrowser.

With the Firefox webbrowser and the [Firebug addon](http://getfirebug.com/) using the network analysis tab I searched for `mp4` (because it is an MP4 video stream) during the video was played. I found a URL like

```
http://mvod.lvlt.rtve.es/resources/TE_NGVA/mp4/5/9/1377759930795.mp4?aksessionid=1377770543247_372201
```

which is the video stream of *Telediario - 8 horas - 29/08/13*.

I have read the question [How to find the stream behind a Flash player](https://superuser.com/questions/114196/how-to-find-the-stream-behind-a-flash-player), but there are only browser solutions (using wireshark to find the stream needs the browser to play the video).

Also the question [How are flash file URLs are protected/hidden on video steaming sites?](https://superuser.com/questions/556917/how-are-flash-file-urls-are-protected-hidden-on-video-steaming-sites) seems to be similar, but has no definite answer.

**So what I want is:** How or where can I find this mp4-URL in the website’s source?

**Update 1:** The AK-session-ID isn’t needed. That means, that the video URL was yesterday

```
 http://mvod.lvlt.rtve.es/resources/TE_NGVA/mp4/5/9/1377759930795.mp4
```

and today

```
http://mvod.lvlt.rtve.es/resources/TE_NGVA/mp4/7/4/1377846494447.mp4
```

At the same time, the only similar name/number is the URL for the preview snapshot of the video (yesterday)

```
http://img.irtve.es/imagenes/telediario-8-horas-29-08-13/1377760554521.JPG
```

and today

```
http://img.irtve.es/imagenes/telediario-8-horas-30-08-13/1377847608923.JPG
```

**Update 2:** I have now extracted the media box which plays the flash video. It looks like

```
<html><body>

    <div>
      <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" height="100%" width="100%" data="http://www.rtve.es//swf/4.2.8/RTVEPlayerVideo.swf">
        <param name="movie" value="/swf/4.2.8/RTVEPlayerVideo.swf"/>
        <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always">
        <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">
        <param name="flashvars" value="assetID=2007594_es_videos&location=alacarta_videos"> 
        <!--  solo video-->
        <param name="wmode" value="opaque">
        <param name="quality" value="high">
      </object>
    </div>

</body></html>
```

The only difference every day seems to be the `assetID`.

When I load this simple webpage, a file

```
http://www.rtve.es/api/videos/2008358/config/alacarta_videos.json
```

gets loaded, with the number being the `assetID`. I still cannot find a connection between the video stream URL and the `assetID` or the json file.

**Update 3:** Oh my god! The strange number for the URL is the seconds since seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC. Because the GNU command

```
date +%s
```

results in 1377856336, which is quite similar to the URL numbers. But the last three digits are missing.

**Update 4:** I have decompiled the source code of the player (flash file) `http://www.rtve.es//swf/4.2.8/RTVEPlayerVideo.swf`. There is no occurence of the video stream domain `http://mvod.lvlt.rtve.es`, that means the player has to get this info from another source. Maybe the json file mentioned in update 2.

Answer (score 1):

I am the webmaster of Descargavideos.tv
I have implemented a script to do what you need, but in php. I cannot help you with scripting it in bash but you can look at the php script here and use it too make the bash script https://github.com/forestrf/Descargavideos/blob/master/secundario/rtve.php
There is a lot of legacy code, code that I wrote before I knew that clean code was a thing and patches, but it works and there are lots of comments so it may be useful for what you need.